# How to connect with linux mint to to wifi wpa2 enterprise with default radius server configuration?

Tags: linux, wifi, authentication, radius, wpa2

I tried to connect to WiFi with WPA2 enterprise authentication to default radius server configuration with Linux mint 19.2 but I can't. 
I set security to WPA2 enterprise, authentication to TTLS, I checked the No CA certification, Inner authentication MSCHAPv2 and correct username and password.
I tried this with Ubuntu and fedora gnome version and there was no problem and They were successfully connected.

Comment: What exactly did you try (that didn't work as expected)? (You can edit your question to add more information, so we can answer and help you more accurately.)

Comment: I wrote down the settings